# how to use mapview in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, mapkit, mkmapview

I want to display a map using two locations in which one updates continously. And also I want to show a custom pin icon in map view.

Comment: Take a look at this. http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 2):

See this link: **[Playing with map kit](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/)**

> I started looking at the Map Kit API for developing a quick and dirty - Find where you parked your car - application.
>
> There is no programming guide for Map Kit yet on the developer pages for Apple, So I decided to share some some of it here.

Part 3 might be what you are looking for:
[image]
<sub>(source: [objectgraph.com](http://blog.objectgraph.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/mapkit31.png))</sub>

Comment: yes absolutely  i need this. i want to show car icon instead of pin.

Answer (score 0):

To Show your icon, Put this code where you have implemented your mapView.

Also add car icon to your project.

```
-(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *view = nil;
    if (annotation != mapView.userLocation) {
        view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];
        if (!view) {
            view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];
            view.canShowCallout = YES;
            view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"];
            }
    }
    return view;
}
```